# How to convert string to regex literal

Tags: c++, regex, tr1

What's the best way to escape an arbitrary `std::wstring` for use inside a regular expression? For example, convert `you owe me $` to `you owe me \$`?

My scenario: I want to use a `std::tr1::wregex` to search for a whole word. So I want to do something like:

```
std::wstring RegexEscape(const std::wstring& inp)
{
    return ?????
}

bool ContainsWholeWord(const std::wstring& phrase, const std::wstring& word)
{
    std::tr1::wregex regex(std::wstring(L"\\b") + RegexEscape(word) + L"\\b");
    return std::tr1::regex_match(phrase, regex);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that it's the cleverest or the most efficient, but I use
something like the following:

```
namespace {
bool
isMeta( char ch )
{
    static bool const meta[UCHAR_MAX] =
    {
        // ...
    };
    return meta[static_cast<unsigned char>( ch )];
}

std::string
sanitizeForRegEx( std::string const& original )
{
    std::string result;
    for ( std::string::const_iterator iter = original.begin();
            iter != original.end();
            ++ iter ) {
        if ( isMeta( *iter ) ) {
            result += '\\';
        result += *iter;
    }
    return result;
}
```

For `wchar_t`, I'd modify `isMeta` to return something like:

```
return ch >= 0 && ch < 128 && meta[ ch ];
```

The initialization of `meta` is a bit of a bore, and the exact values
depend on the regular expressions used (or even the options if
`boost::regex` is used).

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's quite simple! Just use a regular expression to do that!

```
std::wstring szTmp; // some string with $, (, ...
std::wregex rgx_Meta( LR"(([\^\$\\\.\*\+\?\(\)\[\]\{\}\|]))" );
std::wstring strEscaped( std::regex_replace( szTmp, rgx_Meta, LR"(\$1)" ) );
```

This will replace all special character like '$' with '\$'.

Comment: Good idea, but we should add extra slash to the code as the following. std::wstring szTmp(L"x:\\");
 std::wregex rgx_Meta(L"(([\\^\\$\\\\\\.\\*\\+\\?\\(\\)\\[\\]\\{\\}\\|]))");
 std::wstring strEscaped(std::regex_replace(szTmp, rgx_Meta, L"\\$1"));