# how to escape a whole sequence of characters?

Tags: c++, regex

I'm using the following code to "execute" a regular expression in mfc c++

```cpp
std::wregex rx(regularExpression,nFlags);
std::wcmatch res;
std::regex_search(inputString, res, rx);
```

This is used in a dialog where the user types in the `regularExpression` and I search it in my `inputString`.

The user might want to not use a regular expression to find what he wants, in that case I provide an option "whole word" that will match any character in the `regularExpression` variable.

The "whole word" is done by adding enclosing `regularExpression` in `<` and `>`, is there any other special character that will make the `regex_search` method ignore every regex special character, treating them literally, that is enclosed by `<` and `>`?

Comment: What you're asking is not clear. It feels like you've included too much detail that isn't important to your problem, and not enough detail that is.

Comment: A raw string literal might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24533511/1413395

Comment: Just replace any special character separately, start with replacing `\ ` with `\\ `, next `.` with `\.`, and so on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert string to regex literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846510/how-to-convert-string-to-regex-literal)

Comment: @Wimmel sure, but I was wondering if there was a special character that can do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so how can I escape the whole string without having to escape every single special character?

C++ regex does not support any way to do this. You will have to escape each special character if you're going to pass the user's string to the regex matcher.

In some regex engines there are multiple modes, where one mode treats special characters specially by default and escaping them causes them to behave literally, and another mode where characters behave literally by default and have to be escaped in order to behave specially. However C++ regex doesn't support that.

Comment: can I concatenate a variable in that string? like if regularExpression is a CString, regularExpression.Format(R"delimeter(%s)delimeter",regularExpression)?

Comment: The original discussion of raw string literals does not apply to strings input by users, only to string literals you write in the source code.